# Architecture of my application - 1 view asks for a "foreign" model

Tags: django, django-models, architecture

I have 2 apps : accounts ant contracts.

My "accounts" app concerns the users' accounts with a simple model:

```
class UserAccount(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    balance = models.FloatField()
```

My "contracts" app concerns some contract's management. The model is linked to the UserAccount via the auth.User one:

```
class Contract(models.Model):    
    amount_covered = models.FloatField()
    price = models.FloatField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
```

Now, in my "accounts" app, I have a detail view. In this view I want to add the contracts list of the user. So I'm thinking of

```
class AccountDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = UserAccount
    template_name = 'accounts/detail.html'       

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):            
        context = super(AccountDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # HERE I WILL CREATE A contracts LIST, (I DON'T KNOW EXACTLY HOW)


        context['contracts_list'] = contracts
        return context
```

At this point I'm wondering about my architecture: is it OK to mix 2 data models from 2 different apps in a single view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's absolutely okay.

However, if not yet, consider having a look at [reusable app conventions](http://django-reusable-app-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or and/or any other **best practices** articles on organizing your apps and models in particular.